# Why does the quantile function in NumPy return values in between the values from the input array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, statistics

I am trying to understand how the `numpy.quantile` function is working.

I got the expected values for 0.25 and 0.5 quantiles but 0.75 quantile seems to be doing something different.

Data: 13, 21, 21, 40, 42, 48, 55, 72

0.25 × (8+1) = 2.25 → 2nd value of the dataset chosen → 21

0.50 × (8+1) = 4.5 → average of 4th and 5th value → 41

0.75 × (8+1) = 6.75 → 7th value of the dataset chosen → 55

Why does `np.quantile` give 49.75 as the answer for the 0.75 quantile, not 55?

Code and output:

```
import numpy as np

values = [13, 21, 21, 40, 42, 48, 55, 72]
print(len(values))
x = np.quantile(values, [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1])
print(x)
```

Output:

```
8
[13.   21.   41.   49.75 72.  ]
```

Comment: Why are you not surprised that it returns the average of the 4th and 5th value, but are surprised that it returns a value between 6th and 7th value?

Comment: I would suggest that you ask a separate question about how to interpret the values of `plt.boxplot` to keep this question focused on `np.quantile`.

Comment: As far as I read, whenever we get values like 4.5, we take the average value of the data points, one above and one below it. Hence, it seemed justified.
Next, if we were to ignore this rule and go ahead and take the average of the 6th and 7th value, the answer comes out to be (48+55)/2 = 51.5, which doesn't match the output as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the right method for the numpy.quantile i.e. in your case higher would work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

values = [13, 21, 21, 40, 42, 48, 55, 72]
print(len(values))
x = np.quantile(values, [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1], method='higher')
print(x)
```

Documentation at: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html

Comment: The above code is simply picking above the ceiling value of the position calculated. I tested it for the code below while it returns the expected output for 0.75 quantile the answer for 0.25 quantile has changed
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

values = [13, 21, 23, 40, 42, 48, 55, 72]
print(len(values))
x = np.quantile(values, [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1], method='higher')
print(x)`

Comment: The https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html and what I mention clarifies what the numpy.quantile is doing, there are actual description of the calculations in the documentation and why is it doing that. I think getting the answer that you want is pretty simple in python already i.e. get the index-1 of from your calculated value in the array but what you're calculating as quantile, numpy is not.